# XML parsing using windows command line

Tags: xml, parsing, cmd

How can i extract complete line matching certain criteria from XML (Size 1 GB) into different new file?

Below is the instance :

Sample XML File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
<metadata xmlns="log"> <filename>QServer_64Trans_6576_20150325_1049_0.xml</filename> <date>25-03-2015</date> <executablename>E:/Program Files/Quintiq/Quintiq 4.4.0/Bin/QServer_64.exe</executablename> <originalfilename>QServer_64.exe</originalfilename> <productname>Quintiq Server 64-bit</productname> <productversion>4.4.0.13</productversion> <specialbuilddescription>Changelist: 60074</specialbuilddescription> <loggerversion>1.1</loggerversion> </metadata>
<logentries xmlns="log">
<logentry> <index>233509</index> <jobid>14442692</jobid> <status>Finished</status> <result></result> <transactionid>816712145</transactionid> <transactionkind>JobDefinition</transactionkind> <threadname>Trans_0</threadname> <threadid>5912</threadid> <starttime>12:29:50</starttime> <endtime>12:29:50</endtime> <length>00:00:00.031</length> <waitingtime>00:00:00.000</waitingtime> <proctime>00:00:00.015</proctime> <functime>00:00:00.000</functime> <dbtime>00:00:00.016</dbtime> <streamtime>00:00:00.000</streamtime> <nrdatasets>0</nrdatasets> <size>858</size> <constructions>0</constructions> <destructions>0</destructions> <changes>1</changes> <clientid>0</clientid> <ipclient></ipclient> <username>$system/SYSTEM</username> <actionelementtype>Company</actionelementtype> <actionelementname>NotifySenderRecipientAvailable</actionelementname> <actionelementkey>[706273.0.113959]</actionelementkey> <description></description> <messageid></messageid> <lockprofile>[N.[706272.0.12777530]]</lockprofile> <procmem>6744</procmem> <funcmem>126720</funcmem> <dbmem>2696</dbmem> <streammem>6288</streammem> <osvmsize></osvmsize> <freememory></freememory>  </logentry>
<logentry> <index>233510</index> <jobid>14442726</jobid> <status>Started</status> <result></result> <transactionid>816711772</transactionid> <transactionkind>Daemon</transactionkind> <threadname>Trans_1</threadname> <threadid>6208</threadid> <starttime>12:29:51</starttime> <endtime></endtime> <length></length> <waitingtime></waitingtime> <proctime></proctime> <functime></functime> <dbtime></dbtime> <streamtime></streamtime> <nrdatasets></nrdatasets> <size></size> <constructions></constructions> <destructions></destructions> <changes></changes> <clientid>0</clientid> <ipclient></ipclient> <username></username> <actionelementtype>Company</actionelementtype> <actionelementname>DaemonTimedEventHandler</actionelementname> <actionelementkey>[706273.0.88663]</actionelementkey> <description></description> <messageid></messageid> <lockprofile>[N.[706272.0.12777530]]</lockprofile> <procmem></procmem> <funcmem></funcmem> <dbmem></dbmem> <streammem></streammem> <osvmsize></osvmsize> <freememory></freememory>  </logentry>
<logentry> <index>233511</index> <jobid>14442757</jobid> <status>Started</status> <result></result> <transactionid>816712147</transactionid> <transactionkind>ExternalCallMessage</transactionkind> <threadname>Trans_0</threadname> <threadid>5912</threadid> <starttime>12:29:51</starttime> <endtime></endtime> <length></length> <waitingtime></waitingtime> <proctime></proctime> <functime></functime> <dbtime></dbtime> <streamtime></streamtime> <nrdatasets></nrdatasets> <size></size> <constructions></constructions> <destructions></destructions> <changes></changes> <clientid>1290</clientid> <ipclient>10.48.84.220</ipclient> <username>active directory/jonathangonsalvez</username> <actionelementtype>TicketOfWorkCustom</actionelementtype> <actionelementname>Update</actionelementname> <actionelementkey>[103648.0.1464376049]</actionelementkey> <description>BoundCall on INST</description> <messageid></messageid> <lockprofile>[N.[706272.23.358965396]]</lockprofile> <procmem></procmem> <funcmem></funcmem> <dbmem></dbmem> <streammem></streammem> <osvmsize></osvmsize> <freememory></freememory>  </logentry>
<logentry> <index>233512</index> <jobid>14442726</jobid> <status>Finished</status><result></result> <transactionid>816711772</transactionid> <transactionkind>Daemon</transactionkind><threadname>Trans_1</threadname> <threadid>6208</threadid> <starttime>12:29:51</starttime> <endtime>12:29:51</endtime> <length>00:00:00.078</length> <waitingtime>00:00:00.000</waitingtime> <proctime>00:00:00.047</proctime> <functime>00:00:00.000</functime> <dbtime>00:00:00.031</dbtime> <streamtime>00:00:00.002</streamtime> <nrdatasets>0</nrdatasets> <size>6595</size> <constructions>0</constructions> <destructions>1</destructions> <changes>3</changes> <clientid>0</clientid> <ipclient></ipclient> <username></username> <actionelementtype>Company</actionelementtype> <actionelementname>DaemonTimedEventHandler</actionelementname> <actionelementkey>[706273.0.88663]</actionelementkey> <description></description> <messageid></messageid> <lockprofile>[N.[706272.0.12777530]]</lockprofile> <procmem>1060016</procmem> <funcmem>126696</funcmem> <dbmem>2832</dbmem> <streammem>32688</streammem> <osvmsize></osvmsize> <freememory></freememory>  </logentry>
</logentries>
</root>
```

Search Criteria : 
**"Logentry" line which have "Finished" Status & "Daemon" as Transaction Kind.**

```
<logentry>     <status>Finished</status>     <transactionkind>Daemon</transactionkind>
```

All the lines in XML file which match this criteria should be moved to new text file using windows command line.

Comment: I got a solution to do this in Linux server or using Cygwin ; but can can't use anything related to linux.     
Extract "Finished" records for specific Daemon from the newly created .txt file and output to a next file just those events

`grep "DaemonCompanyTime" QServer_64Trans_*_2015*.xml| grep Finished  > DaemonCompanyTime_2015.csv`

 

Replace xml tags  with double quotes (file will shrink by ~70%, original version preserved in in .bak file)

`sed -i.bak 's/<[^>]*>/"/g' DaemonCompanyTime_2015.csv`

Answer (score 0):

I would start off by saying "use C# or XSLT" or "omgwtf? powershell!", but then I read the 1GB part.  Unless you are ok with loading the file into RAM, you would have to use `XmlReader`.

If you are ok with disgusting, try `findstr /v Started input.xml > out.xml`.  This will get all lines from `input.xml` which don't contain the word Started.  No guarantees that this will not horribly corrupt the XML, though.

For reference, here is powershell:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content .\input.xml)
$xml.Root.LogEntries.LogEntry | where { $_.status -eq "Finished" } | ft
```